# How do I know the best place to use 'using'?

Tags: c#, using-statement

I'm somewhat new to c#, more accustomed to scripting languages.  I like the idea of 'using', you instantiate an object, and then you operate within its scope as long as you need it, then you let it dispose of itself when it's done its purpose.

But, it's not natural for me.  When people show me examples using it, I recognize it as a good tool for the job, but it never occurs to me to solve problems with it in my own programming.

How can I recognize good places to use `using` and how do I use it in conjunction with try-catch blocks.  Do they go inside the block, or do you usually want to enclose a using statement within a try block?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I rarely write try/catch blocks - most exceptions get thrown up to (near) the top of the stack. If I *do* need a try/catch block, I'm not sure I'm particularly consistent between putting it inside the `using` statement vs outside. It really depends on whether you want the resource to be disposed before of after your exception handling code is run.

If you're asking about *when* you should be writing `using` statements - any time you "own" an object which implements `IDisposable` (either directly or indirectly through inheritance) and control its lifetime. That's usually an object which uses an unmanaged resource like a file handle or network connection. It's not always hugely obvious, but you learn through experience. Almost *anything* to do with IO will be disposable, and Windows handles (for fonts etc) are similar.

Comment: To clarify objects that implement IDisposable directly or through inheritance (as danieltalsky is "somewhat new to C#").

Comment: Well, by "somewhat new to C#" I mean, "have been writing commercial code in C# for less than 8 months".  I was, for instance, already familiar with the connection of "using" to "IDisposable" which I do mention in the question.  It was the "lifetime control" part I was missing.

Answer (score 18):

`using` can only be used with types that implement `IDisposable`; it guarantees that the `Dispose()` method will be called even if an error occurs.

This code:

```
using (MyDisposableType x = new MyDisposableType())
{  
    // use x
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
MyDisposableType x = new MyDisposableType();
try
{  
    // use x
}
finally 
{ 
    x.Dispose(); 
}
```

Comment: So... use it on any object that implements IDisposable?  Always?

Comment: And what about exception handling?

Comment: Note that you should never put transaction logic in finally as it is not absolutely guaranteed to run. Until we get transactional memory at least. E.g. If you pull out the power plug finally won't run!

Comment: how would you do it then? Prevent the code from doing something at a power down :D

Comment: It would be a shame to leak resources by not disposing them on a power down :)

Comment: Weird, I was told that finally is _always_ guaranteed to run, whether there is an exception or not. Haven't thought about the power going down, though... ;P

Comment: @Jonathan Parker - there is no better place to put transactional logic than in 'finally'.

Answer (score 3):

I use to think of it as "Use it every time when type implements IDisposable and you you're not goinng to need this particular instance any more".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how to creatively use it within your own designs, look through some of your own code for situations where a particular bit of code absolutely must execute before the enclosing block is exited. These are the situations where `try`/`finally` or `using` can help you.

In particular, if you've tried to achieve this by catching all exceptions, then you really must change to `try`/`finally` or `using` instead.

If the pattern occurs several times, you could create a class that implements `IDisposable` in order to capture the pattern, and allowing you to invoke the pattern with the `using` statement. But if you have a specific case that appears to be a one-off, then just use `try`/`finally`.

The two are very similar, really - `using` is specified in terms of `try`/`finally`, but even if we only had `using`, we could build `try`/`finally` ourselves:

```
public class DisposeAnything : IDisposable
{
    public Action Disposer;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Disposer();
    }
}
```

Now you could say:

```
using (new DisposeAnything 
      {
          Disposer = () => File.Delete(tempFileName) 
      })
{
    // blah
}
```

Which is the same as:

```
try
{
    // blah
}
finally
{
    File.Delete(tempFileName);
}
```

Just think of it as a way to get some code to execute upon leaving a scope.

Comment: Hey, parameterizing the dispose logic is an interesting idea. I imagine there are many ways to do that. Cool.

Comment: Taken to the above extreme, there's not a lot of point to it! But yes there are probably many half-way cases. You may find this discussion interesting: http://incrediblejourneysintotheknown.blogspot.com/2009/02/functional-replacement-for-using.html

Answer (score 1):

WHat Mitch said, plus..

You can use the using statement outside or inside a try..catch block it really would depend on what you are trying to achieve i.e. whether you reasonably expect something to throw an exception whilst using a particular object which you plan to recover from, for example.

By the same token, you could also Dispose of an object which implements IDisposable in a finally block if you needed to.

Answer (score 1):

Use *using* when you need deterministic object disposal. For example, if you open a file, the file is locked. You will often want the file to be closed as soon as possible so that other programs could access it. If you don't use *using* and write smth like:

```
System.IO.FileStream writeStream = new System.IO.FileStream( fileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate ) );
System.IO.BinaryWriter writer = new System.IO.BinaryWriter( writeStream ) );
//do smth
```

and an exception occurs during "do smth" you don't know when the objects operating on a file are actually disposed and file is closed. With *using* you know for sure that once you've left the *using* statement block - either directly or via exception the object in the *useing* statement is disposed by calling IDisposable::Dispose:

```
using( System.IO.FileStream writeStream = new System.IO.FileStream( fileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate ) ) {
    using( System.IO.BinaryWriter writer = new System.IO.BinaryWriter( writeStream ) ) {
        //do stmth
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the object *isn't* finalized. It's only disposed. Finalization and disposal are very different. Usually disposal will suppress a finalizer (if there is one) but they're not the same thing.

Comment: "Use using when you need deterministic object disposal." It seem to me that if an object implements IDisposable you should always dispose it if the object is not needed any more. By implementing IDisposable the object says "I (might) use resources that needs to be disposed".

Comment: What if implementation of the object in question changes and disposing at once becomes critical ? What is the benefit of non disposing right after usage ?

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose a using inside a try/catch block and you can enclose a try/catch block inside a using.

One situation where using is nice is when you are doing database operations using DBConnection and DBCommands:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
  // do something here
}
```

Now when you leave the using blocks your command is disposed and the connection is closed.

Answer (score 1):

What Mitch said is right. So the main use of using is to ensure that IDisposable objects get disposed of, *without* having to code a try/catch or try/finally statement.

Now, there's a more advanced use you might find interesting as well. When you use a using statement, the compiler generates a try/finally, and it also generates a call to Dispose() for you inside of the finally that it generates. You can use this Dispose() method as a "hook" to do anything you want ... doesn't have to be related to releasing resources.

For example, Jeffrey Richter uses this in a timer object he wrote. You can do something like this with it (conceptual only):

```
using(var x = new Timer())
{
  // Do the operation you want timed
}

// Now, the timer has been stopped, because the 
// compiler-generated call to Dispose() has already 
// occurred, and Jeffrey uses Dispose() to stop 
// the timer.
```

Comment: Seems little bit tricky. After the closing brace you don't have access to x. How can you then take advantage of the stopped timer ?

Comment: Yes, that's true. In the case of Richter's timer, he outputs the elapsed time (and the number of garbage collections that have occurred) to the Console. So he had no other need to reference the object after the closing brace.

Comment: However, there are ways to achieve that too if you want. The object could be told to fire an event or place results into a collection. Or you could parameterize the object with a lambda action to perform inside itself. But this is getting too far away from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If a class implements IDisposable, it's probably for good reason. So any class that implements IDisposable should be disposed.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it is what is known as "syntactic sugar" and will produce the same IL as a try/finally dispose construct, it is really just a nice way of "short-handing" such code.

I like to use it to simplify sections of code where disposable objects are used a lot i.e. access to resources such as files and graphics objects and I want to make sure that I don't forget to handle the disposing of the resource object.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that when the Dispose method is known to do notice, so programmers don't bother calling it as it seems pointless. However, if the object implements IDisposable it's (hopefully) for a reason and future versions of that object may actually have code in the Dispose method - so always call it.